# How do I force straight edges in a (simple) Digraph?

Tags: graphviz

I have the following simple digraph:

```
digraph clientproxyserver {
  "Client" -> "Proxy" [ label="Request from Client" ];
  "Proxy" -> "Server" [ label="Forwarded Request" ];
  "Server" -> "Proxy" [ label="Response from Server" ];
  "Proxy" -> "Client" [ label="Forwarded Response" ];
}
```

Running this trough `dot`:

```
dot -Grankdir=LR -Nshape=box -Nheight=1 -Tpng -ocps.png cps.gv
```

I get the following result:

[image: Resulting graph]

What can I do to make the two bottom edges straight lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what usually the option [`splines=ortho`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:splines) is for:

```
digraph clientproxyserver {
    rankdir=LR;
    node[shape=box, height=1];
    splines=ortho
  "Client" -> "Proxy" [ label="Request from Client" ];
  "Proxy" -> "Server" [ label="Forwarded Request" ];
  "Server" -> "Proxy" [ label="Response from Server" ];
  "Proxy" -> "Client" [ label="Forwarded Response" ];
}
```

Unfortunately, the placement of the edges/labels is very confusing:

[image: otho layout]

In my experience, `ortho` splines produce rarely a satisfying result.

An other option would be to use `splines=polyline`:

[image: polyline layout]