# How to make primary arrows straight with Graphviz when there are reverse links to the same nodes?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Given the following graph:

```
digraph g {
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=box];

  A;
  { rank = same;
    B; C; D; E;
  };
  A -> B [label="144"];
  B -> A [label="261"; constraint=false];
  B -> C [label="144"];
  C -> B [label="261"; constraint=false];
  C -> D [label="144"];
  D -> C [label="261"; constraint=false];
  D -> E [label="144"];
  E -> D [label="261"; constraint=false];

  B -> n1 [label="144"];
  n1 -> B [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n1 -> n2 [label="144"];
  n2 -> n1 [label="261"; constraint=false];

  C -> n3 [label="144"];
  n3 -> C [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n3 -> n4 [label="144"];
  n4 -> n3 [label="261"; constraint=false];

  D -> n5 [label="144"];
  n5 -> D [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n5 -> n6 [label="144"];
  n6 -> n5 [label="261"; constraint=false];

  E -> n7 [label="144"];
  n7 -> E [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n7 -> n8 [label="144"];
  n8 -> n7 [label="261"; constraint=false];
};
```

The resulting output is:

[image: graphviz output]

This is almost what I want (in particular it took a lot of trouble to figure out how to make that straight line of letter nodes in the second rank), but my problem is with the way that the edge arrows are drawn in the vertical nodes.

What I want is for the "forward" arrow (the one going right/down in the graph, and the one without `constraint=false`) to be straight, and the "reverse" arrow (going left/up in the graph, with `constraint=false`) to be curved.  And in both cases I want the labels to be out of the way of each other.  (For the vertical arrows, this probably means pushing the label to the other side.)

I've tried playing with setting groups and weights but so far nothing has seemed to help swap the vertical arrows.  And I haven't found anything that will move the label to the other side.

I also tried using the `splines` setting but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force straight edges in a (simple) Digraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907121/how-do-i-force-straight-edges-in-a-simple-digraph)

Comment: No, the splines setting does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing edge placement is very difficult.
Does this meet your requirements - it uses ports to tweak the edge placement.

```
digraph g {
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=box];
  
  A;
  { rank = same;
    B; C; D; E;
  };
  A -> B [label="144"];
  B -> A [label="261"; constraint=false];
  B -> C [label="144"];
  C -> B:se [label="261"; constraint=false];
  C -> D [label="144"];
  D -> C:se [label="261"; constraint=false];
  D -> E [label="144"];
  E -> D:se [label="261"; constraint=false];

  B -> n1 [label="144"];
  n1 -> B [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n1 -> n2 [label="144"];
  n2 -> n1 [label="261"; constraint=false];

  C -> n3 [label="144"];
  n3 -> C [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n3 -> n4 [label="144"];
  n4 -> n3 [label="261"; constraint=false];

  D -> n5 [label="144"];
  n5 -> D [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n5 -> n6 [label="144"];
  n6 -> n5 [label="261"; constraint=false];

  E -> n7 [label="144"];
  n7 -> E [label="261"; constraint=false];
  n7 -> n8 [label="144"];
  n8 -> n7 [label="261"; constraint=false];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works for me, thanks.  I had tried setting the "down arrow" to `:s -> :n` explicitly but by itself that wasn't working, but just forcing the `:se` corner does seem to do the trick.